# Dealing with 16 bits radiometric images in OpenCv

Tags: python, image, opencv, normalization, image-segmentation

So, I extracted the radiometric raw data of thermograms (exiftools) and needed to do some processing to enhance the visualization in order to annotate these images to get mask for segmentation later. However, I need to keep the radiometric values unchanged (they are 16bits grayscale thermal images). The extracted raw png is too gray and I barely can see the image, so I thought on doing some basic processing (min-max normalization) to enhance the visualization. For this image, for example, the max and min values range from 19663 to 16792, but it varies. When I normalize using mix/max (code below) the image looks great for annotation, but it stretches the values and I don't want it.

Im using this loop to process these images:

```
for filename in glob.iglob("*.png"):
if "raw" in filename:
    img = cv2.imread(filename, -1)
    #max = np.max(img)
    #min = np.min(img)
    img_16bits = cv2.normalize(img, None, 0, 65535, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype = cv2.CV_16U)
    basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]
    cv2.imwrite(basename+"_"+"16bits"+".png",img_16bits)
```

Interesting enough, when I plot the image using plt.imshow with grayscale cmap, the image looks great and the values are unchanged, same when I drag it in ImageJ (it automatically corrects the contrast). I tried several things to change this code to get where I want, without luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Images (raw image / processed with stretched values):

[image: Raw Image]

[image: Processed]

Comment: Can´t you keep two versions of the image? One normalized, for visualization, and the unprocessed image for whatever processing you need next? If I understood correctly, do you want a unique image that combines the good visualization (maybe the color map) but with the unnormalized pixel values? Sounds like you want an indexed image.

Comment: Yes, I could keep both, but it wouldn't be practical for my project. Indeed I want a combination of good visualization while keeping the unnornalized values. I will need the the values for temperature conversion and extracting features, for example. ImageJ gives a good visualization and keep the values as I drag the raw image into the program. So it would be really helpful to understand what is happening there and how I could implement that in my code to automatize this process.

Comment: matplotlib does visualizations. what makes you think a plot is data? it's not, it's a visualization. the values aren't "unchanged". they are colormapped, even if gray. completely different. -- I'm sorry, but you have to differentiate between the data and a visualization of it. you speak of annotation. what makes you think the _visualization_ you use for annotation MUST go on to be any kind of data? the visualization is a *proxy* of the data, for annotation. you keep the annotation, discard the visualization, and associate the annotation with the data. I do not see the problem at all.

Comment: I think you might need a deeper understanding of "GUI".

Comment: Use skimage rescale_intensity() to stretch your image. You can control both the input values and the output values and the dtype via .astype().